# Как установить сертификат Windows через Python?

Tags: python, windows

Как посредством Python можно установить сертификат с расширением `.pfx` в доверенный корневой центр сертификации?
При установке нужно задавать пароль.

Comment: А чем стандартные средства Windows не подходят? Какова реальная задача?